# Periscope dryer vent in exterior wall

Tags: dryer, vent, ventilation

Our exterior wall has 2x4 framing and we wanted to see if we can run a periscope vent for the dryer in the exterior wall before venting out. We are trying to save some space in the laundry area so wanted to know if that is an option. Could it interfere with the wall insulation? Any other considerations to be aware of?

This is [an example of a vent](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/thd-dryer-periscope-0-inch-18-inch/1000818693) from the home depot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This vent should not interfere with standard insulation. If you have to remove some of the insulation to fit it in make up for it by adding insulation to the vent. Wrapping the vent pipe with insulation is a good idea. So the air remains warm until it exits the house. This reduces the chance of the water condensing inside your house or dryer vent. Attach insulation with foil based duct tape and caulk where pipe exits the house.

Comment: This type of vent is what I have used on basement dryer installs I don’t see why there would be any problem using it.+

Comment: I don't see a problem with the vent. I do agree that burying it in a wall seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put the vent inside the wall. There are a number of reasons for this:

1. An exterior wall with just 2x4 studs should have that space full of insulation. Trying to put the vent inside the wall will either compress the insulation or require removing some of the insulation. In both cases the loss of insulating capability is not good.
2. Trying to install this inside the wall requires opening up the wall and then re-patching.
3. Vents like this capture a certain amount of lint dust over time and they need to be taken apart and cleaned. I use one and have to clean it every couple of years. The lint gathers because the sharp turns in the air flow cause the lint to fall out of the air currents.
4. Dryers only last a certain number of years and have to be replaced. If you customize for your current dryer by burying the adjustable vent in the wall cavity you will no doubt be having to re-open the wall at the time a new dryer comes along.

The chance of saving much more space when using a periscope type vent is unlikely. Like I said before I have one behind my dryer and it is very difficult to reach behind the dryer to tighten the clamps on the dryer and pipe that sticks out of the wall. If the space behind the dryer was any less than the minimal amount required for a periscope vent it would not be possible to get to the clamps.

Comment: With all due respect Mike all dryer vents will capture a certain amount of lint dust over the years.  It's suggested  that they be inspected and cleaned once a year.  Most homes that have venting installed at construction  don't have to reopen the wall when they buy a new dryer.  If the OP installs this to accommodate a standard dryer, it will be ok for the future

Comment: The issue is the proposal to bury the vent in the wall. That seems to me likely to be a source of unnecessary problems. Surface-mounted on the wall with a straight vent at the top that goes thru to outside makes more sense to me.